# VB function that strips accents from a string

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to have a function which takes a string and returns the same string without any accented letters. Instead, the accented letters should return the same letter without the accent. This function is not working:

```
function StripAccents(str)

accent   = "ÈÉÊËÛÙÏÎÀÂÔÖÇèéêëûùïîàâôöç"
noaccent = "EEEEUUIIAAOOCeeeeuuiiaaooc"

currentChar = ""
result = ""
k = 0
o = 0

FOR k = 1 TO len(str)
    currentChar = mid(str,k, 1)
    o = InStr(accent, currentChar)
    IF o > 0 THEN
        result = result & mid(noaccent,k,1)
    ELSE
        result = result & currentChar
    END IF
NEXT

StripAccents = result

End function

testStr = "Test : à é À É ç"
response.write(StripAccents(testStr))
```

This is the result using the above:

```
Test : E E Eu EE E
```

Comment: Accents are a subset of what you're transforming. The correct term is [diacritic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregarding possible encoding problems - you must change

```
result = result & mid(noaccent,k,1)
```

to

```
result = result & mid(noaccent,o,1)
```

Comment: Thanks. That was silly. Although I do seem to have encoding problems also.. I'm using UTF-8. Is that not correct?

Comment: @greener - as you can't "use UTF-8" in VBScript, you need to compose a new question that describes your "encoding problems" and what you did to cause them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the example code with the correction added

[Then I added more characters](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8392f4d3-e016-4337-9d37-fb20fecd1425/converting-string-with-accented-characters-to-nonaccented-equivalent)

Giving:

```
accent   = "àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙäëïöüÄËÏÖÜâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚðÐýÝãñõÃÑÕšŠžŽçÇåÅøØ"
noaccent = "aeiouAEIOUaeiouAEIOUaeiouAEIOUaeiouAEIOUdDyYanoANOsSzZcCaAoO"
```

Now I realised that there are a few more to deal with, namely

```
æ
Æ
ß
```

These need converting first using a simple replace them with `ae` `AE` and `ss`

Then it works fine other than it is important to not have `<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>` or similar in the code

However having meta `charset="UTF-8"` in the header is not a big issue, it converts fine.

So if the code is needed on the page with `<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>` in it, I do not know any answer to that

Thanks for the code greener, very useful for dealing with the common diacriticals :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do a decomposition normalization first (NFD).  I think you could do this in VBA using a call to the WinAPI function NormalizeString (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319093(v=vs.85).aspx).  Then, you could remove the accent code points.

Comment: The question is tagged "VBScript", not "VBA".